# How to work with constrained relationships in Laravel 5.4 Eloquent

Tags: php, database, eloquent, relationship, laravel-5.4

I have the following tables:

```
Schema::create('shop_products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->text('description');
            $table->decimal('price', 4, 2);
            $table->decimal('weight', 6, 2)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Schema::create('shop_orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Schema::create('shop_order_products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('shop_order_id');
            $table->integer('shop_product_id');
            $table->integer('number');

            $table->unique(['shop_order_id', 'shop_product_id']);
        });
```

And the following models:

```
<?php

namespace Shop\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Product extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
}

----

<?php

namespace Shop\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Order extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Shop\Models\ShopOrderProduct');
    }
}

----

<?php

namespace Shop\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class OrderProduct extends Model
{
    /**
     * All of the relationships to be touched.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $touches = ['order'];



    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Shop\Models\ShopOrder');
    }

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Shop\Models\Product');
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a purchase action which gets/creates an order for the current user and adds the product to the order.

I don't want multiple orders in the session, and I don't want multiple instances of products in the order.

So far I have:

```
public function purchase(Request $request)
{
    // load the product based on a URL slug value from a POST request
    $product = Product::where('slug', $request->input('slug'))->firstOrFail();

    // look for an orderID saved in the session
    if ($orderId = session('shop.order.id')) {
        // orderId exists, so get the order which matches
        $order = Order::find($orderID);
    } else {
        // otherwise create a new order and save the orderId to the session
        $order = Order::create();
        session(['shop.order.id' => $order->id]);
    }

    // this is where I'm getting stuck
    // I want to (simply) ensure that the product has not been previously
    // added to the order - if it has, then I want to increment the 'number'
    // field - otherwise, I want to create a new instance of the product in
    // the order.
    $orderProduct = new OrderProduct();
    $orderProduct->product()->save($product);

    // move on to the cart to show the current order
    return redirect()->route('shop_cart');
}
```